# Teams Bot - Adding scanning capability

Tags: c#, botframework, qr-code, microsoft-teams

We have built a Teams bot using `bot v4 framework` using `C#`. We wanted to integrate the `QR code` scanning feature inside the bot , like if user clicks on a button the camera pops up and scans the QR code .Is scanning a QR code inside a Teams bot built using bot framework v4 possible ?

Comment: Hi @Ashish Kumar,

Thanks for contacting us!

A bot built using the Microsoft Bot Framework is really just a website. If you're using the c# sdk, then the bot application is actually a WebApi site. Messages from client applications are sent through channel connectors, then to the bot. Client applications can be built using whatever language or platform you choose. Here is a reference to the [Bot Framework Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-overview?view=azure-bot-service-4.0).

Comment: The method used to capture the QR code is entirely up to you. You can then send the QR Code to your bot as an attachment to an Activity. The method for capturing the QR code is outside the scope of the Bot Builder itself.

Comment: @Rama-MSFT Can we open the camera in Teams bot to capture the image rather than attaching an image in a message , I understand we can process the image for QR code outside the scope of teams bots

Comment: @AshishKumar We are checking with our Engineering Team for this possibility. Will update you as soon as we get any information.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this feature is not supported yet. Please raise a User Voice. Microsoft will always focus on customer’s feedback and experience and based on those, new features will be added to the service.